# Display the output on the terminal and tail the last 10 lines to log file

Tags: linux, bash

I need to run a script and output the full contents to the terminal.
I then want to get the last 10 lines from the terminal output and put them in a log file.
I have tried using `./script.sh 2>&1 | tail -10 > log.log`
but this stops the output to the terminal.

Comment: ./script.sh 2>&1 | tail -10 > log.log  this seems to be working. Do you want the output to be printed to console as well ??

Comment: yes I want the full log to be printed to the console and the last 10 lines to be added to a log file

Comment: As mentioned by Stony, use tee command for that,  
./script.sh 2>&1 | tail -10 | tee log.log

Comment: this will only print the last 10 lines to the console. I need the full log printed to the console

Comment: ./script.sh 2>&1 | tee >(tail -10 >file.txt)

will work for this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leverage process substitution of `bash` with `tee`:

```
./script.sh |& tee >(tail -10 >file.txt)
```

`|&` is a shortcut for sending both STDOUT and STDERR over the pipe.

`tee` redirects it's STDIN to both STDOUT and to the file(s) given as argument(s) -- we have used process substitution to get a file descriptor and used `tail -10 >file.txt` inside process substitution to save the desired content.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to use the `tee` command. Then you can pipe to a file and your console.

```
ls -a | tee output.file
```

Comment: ./script.sh 2>&1 | tail -10 | tee log.log  will work in this case