# Grep the last lines of ouput

Tags: scripting, grep, sh

When running a shell command without redirection, I sometimes **in hindsight** want to process the output I see on screen.

I often want to "grep" the output of a console **in hindsight**. I might not be able to run the command again with proper redirection: (The command might take a long time to run. The command might have produced side effects).

Is there some shell wizardry which I could use to: "Grep the last 100 lines of output in the terminal", **without re-executing the command again** with a redirect?

My current solution is to scroll up manually, and copy paste the last lines of output into a text file. I would prefer a fully scripted solution instead...

Comment: `your_command | tail -n 100 > file`?

Comment: the problem is "in hindsight". When I am not able to run the command *again* with redirection. It's more of a "I ran this command without redirection, and now I have some intersting output on screen"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display the output on the terminal and tail the last 10 lines to log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44903679/display-the-output-on-the-terminal-and-tail-the-last-10-lines-to-log-file)

Comment: Cyrus, no that does not work. Redirecting the command into tail,tee,awk,sed,wc,python,etc... will not work. They all require me to pipe the command into something in advance. The whole premise of this question is **in hindsight**: Example: When you did **not** pipe your command in advance, and it is impractical to run the command again with a pipe.

Comment: Maybe you can pipe your command to `tee` and output it to a file. That way you will have the commands output both in your terminal and inside file.

Comment: @eshalev: When the text has been output, the possibilities depend exclusively on the terminal used.

Comment: If you always start `screen` when you log in so everything you do is managed by `screen` then there may be a way to do what you want since per the man page `There is a scrollback history buffer for each virtual terminal` so maybe you can find where that buffer is stored if it's stored in a file (idk) and grep in it. See https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen and/or look for similar programs such as `tmux` (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html) if that doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there some shell wizardry which I could use to: "Grep the last 100 lines of output in the terminal", without re-executing the command again with a redirect?

No.

> My current solution is to scroll up manually, and copy paste the last lines of output into a text file. I would prefer a fully scripted solution instead...

Exactly, you have to use the program that is used to **view** the output, be it a graphical terminal in a graphical environment. Some such terminals allow to save the current "state" of terminal output to a file. Next time - use `tmux` or `screen` - i.e. a program that simulates the terminal.